# How to construct a binary tree (breadth first or level order) based on individual user inputs?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I want to add elements recursively by making the leaf nodes as root nodes, from left to right.

Below is my code where I created 3 nodes but unable to insert new nodes correctly.

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data


class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = node(root)

    def insert(self,value):
        left = 0
        right = 0
        if self.root is not None:
            if self.root.left is None:
                self.root.left = node(value)

            elif self.root.right is None:
                self.root.right = node(value)

            .
            .
            .        

tree = BinaryTree(1)
tree.insert(2)
tree.insert(3)#---> till this it's okay.
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(5)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(7)
```

I want the tree to look like this

```
          1
     2        3
  4    5   6     7
```

Comment: How would you do BFS on any graph? How would you do it on a tree (which is a type of graph)? Apply that logic to your code - that's all. If there exists child node, add it to some list (it should be queue, because breadth-first requires FIFO, but Python types are flexible and normal list should do it if you know how to use it) of nodes to check, first empty child is place to insert your value and exit the function.

Comment: The logic would work if there is no left or right child of the root. You'd have to go beyond that, say suppose if both left and right of the root are present, where would you insert the next node?  Try modifying the code since you'd be inserting left to right.

Comment: Thanks for your help. With the help of a queue (python List) i was able to implement it. The trick is to 'not remove the root node from the queue until both the left and right nodes are inserted'